# Presumably the owner of an API wants to remove a private key from the question

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, specific-question

While I was going through suggested edits, I've come up with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43275890/data-disappear-out-of-uniurlconnection). In the edit, a key is removed from the source in the question by the editor and she said that she is the owner of an api and want the key removed. I do not know that if that is true so I rejected the edit. Is that OK?

Comment: I do not know if it is possible to give link to an edit request directly.

Comment: You can get a link to the suggested edit directly from the post's [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43275890/timeline).

Comment: Well it doesn't really matter if the editor is the owner of the API or not, the key shouldn't be there, in any case. I wonder if a mod can edit the history to remove that key from any version. -Edit- Brad wrote in the dupe, that mods can't do that themselves.

Comment: @Tom Mods can remove the information and it takes multiple mods in order to make the change and review it. That is something that they where given in order to speed up the removal of sensitive information.

Comment: 1rst Rule of credential leek, Do not talk about it! 
Edit, flag and remain calm till mod fix it. A few mounth ago, Someone came with an Db issue in his question Full credential was exposed! `$username="""; $password="";` After 25min of call out "let me deface my question", a fix was made in the Db directly by someone else.

Comment: I found this question useful because searching Meta for "private key in question" and other variations didn't lead me to the dupe target.  Thanks for the question.